# How to get coordinates of circle in the JS Leatflet-draw plugin

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This question about JS, the library Leaflet.js and plugin Leaflet-draw.

how can I get coordinates of circle (radius)? For instance, getting coordinates (the first point) of rect, polygon, etc I'm using this:

```
var a = layer.getLatLngs(); 
arrY[i] = a[0].lat; 
arrX[i] = a[0].lng;
```

But for circle it isn't working. Help me please. Sorry for my eng yet once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [leaflet circle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) reference for all of the available items.

Sounds like you are looking for getLatLng() and getRadius() for your immediate need.

```
var latLng = layer.getLatLng();
var radius = layer.getRadius();
```